# Sublists from a python list such that first sublist contains first 2 elements of list, then first 3 elements and so on and Num as 3rd, 4th and so on

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested-loops

From a given list, I have to create sublists that follow a sequence as first 2 elements, then first 3 elements, then first 4 elements and so on from the given list and corresponding num as 3rd element, 4th element, 5th element, and so on. Used the below-given code, but it is not giving the 0 indexed list element i.e. 1. What's wrong?

```
list = [1, 3, 2, 10, 4, 8, 6]
list2 = []
Num = None
for i in range(2,len(list)):
    print(f"i = {i}")
    Num = list[i]
    for j in range(0,i):
        print(f"j = {j}")
    list2.append(list[j])
    print(f"\tlist2 = {list2}\tNum = {Num}")
    print(f".........................................................")
```

Desired Output:

```
list2 = [1, 3]  Num = 2
list2 = [1, 3, 2]  Num = 10
list2 = [1, 3, 2, 10]   Num = 4
list2 = [1, 3, 2, 10, 4]    Num = 8
list2 = [1, 3, 2, 10, 4, 8]   Num = 6
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I'm not quite following what you're trying to do.  Please include the expected output and the actual output.    That said, the reason why you're not getting the 0th element is that your range starts at 2.

Comment: Expected Output as : list1, Num1 = [1, 3], 2
list2, Num2 = [1, 3, 2], 10
list3, Num3 = [1, 3, 2, 10], 4
list4, Num4 = [1, 3, 2, 10, 4], 8
list5, Num5 = [1, 3, 2, 10, 4, 8], 6 But by this code list[j=0] = 1 is missing from all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
a = [1, 3, 2, 10, 4, 8, 6]

for i in range(2,len(a)):
    print(f'list2 = {a[:i]} Num={a[i]}')
```

Output

```py
list2 = [1, 3] Num=2
list2 = [1, 3, 2] Num=10
list2 = [1, 3, 2, 10] Num=4
list2 = [1, 3, 2, 10, 4] Num=8
list2 = [1, 3, 2, 10, 4, 8] Num=6
```

Comment: Desired output:                                                                                                    data = [1, 3], num = 2
data = [1, 3, 2], num = 10
data = [1, 3, 2, 10], num = 4
data = [1, 3, 2, 10, 4], num = 8
data = [1, 3, 2, 10, 4, 8], num = 6

Comment: your code with some modification: `a = [1, 3, 2, 10, 4, 8, 6]
data = []
num = None
for i in range(2,len(a)):
    data.append(a[:i])
    num = a[i]
    print(f"data = {data}, num = {num}")` This is not giving desired output

Comment: I have updated the code to match your desired output structure

Answer (score -1):

try changing

```
for i in range(2,len(list)):
```

condition to

```
for i in range(1,len(list)):
```

so the loop would start on the first element of the given list. This should solve the problem.

Comment: I have to get sublists as first 2 elements, then first 3 elements, then first 4 elements and so on. While using the above code print(f"j = {j}") , it is printing j = 0 but not appending element list[j=0] i.e. 1 to the list 2????